# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MySqlConnection'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to join several tables created by ASP.NET Core identity. However the above error keeps getting thrown.

This is the join statement:

```
var customers = 
    await context.Users
                 .Join(context.UserRoles, user => user.Id, urole => urole.UserId, (user, urole) => new { user, urole })
                 .Join(context.Roles, a => a.urole.RoleId, role => role.Id, (a, role) => new { a, role })
                 .Where(s => s.role.Name == role.SystemRole)
                 .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: can you show us where you defined your MySQLConnection? if it was at some part of the code where it went out of scope, GC might have disposed your connection.

Comment: Could you pls share the appsettings.json how do you configure the connection string?

Comment: Please add the code that sets up your DbContext and the context initialization. Do other queries against the DbContext seem to run as expected? I removed my answer if it is an injected DbContext then that should not apply, but seeing more of the code initializing the DbContext may highlight something. Does the exception occur right on that line or at the end of the method containing that line?

Comment: @Steve Py the exception occurs right after that line. `DbContext setup : public partial class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }` Other queries throw different errors as well.

Comment: for example : `                var ticketExists = context.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == ticketStatus.TicketId);` throws : System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Aspnetuser.TicketAssignedToNavigations' of type 'ICollection<Ticket>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.' Which has made accessing the db for anything impossible

Comment: for more context, the projectwasn't configured with identity before and was using database first appoach. Addition of the Identity with its code-first approach made everything break

Comment: If you are introducing Identity into an existing project that had a DbContext, create a separate IdentityDbContext instance from the AppDbContext.. So for instance AppDbContext: DbContext and AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext. If you want to reference something like Users in your AppDbContext, create a simplified User entity to register with AppDbContext but leave User/UserRole/Role etc and auth checks using the AuthDbContext with the entities it creates. Regular interactions use AppDbContext, auth checks use AuthDbContext.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my Repository method was using async Task but the controller method wasn't. Adding the appropriate types to the controller solved the issue.